# How to change the date format in a list of dates

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I want to import data from multiple csv files. Every business day a new CSV file is produces and the first 8 digits of the file name is the date in question. I want to import the data from the last 100 files every day. So, I thought I wanted to make a list of dates and use that in a for loop to collect all the data. To create a date range I did the following:

```
>>> datelist = pd.bdate_range(end=pd.datetime.today(), periods = 100).tolist
>>> datelist
<bound method DatetimeIndex.tolist of DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-07', '2015-07-08', '2015-07-09', '2015-07-10',
 dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')>
```

Now, how do I change the date format from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyymmdd ??

Comment: check into the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html). morespecifically, [this method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and [this method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat)

Comment: You probably want `.tolist()` instead of `.tolist`.  As written, `datelist` is being assigned to the `tolist` function object itself, instead of the _results_ of calling the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension together with `strftime`.

```
datelist = [d.strftime('%Y%m%d') 
            for d in pd.bdate_range(end=pd.datetime.today(), periods = 100)]

>>> datelist
['20151110',
 '20151111',
 '20151112',
 '20151113',
 '20151116',
 '20151117',
 '20151118',
 '20151119',
 '20151120',
 '20151123', ...]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot:)